# Make the 3rd (merge preview) pane in TortoiseMerge bigger

Tags: tortoise-svn

How can I make the 3rd (merge preview) pane in TortoiseMerge bigger? Right now it shows 2 lines.

Comment: DaveParillo is right the line diff bar only shows two lines and can't be changed. I must have been think of a different merge app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the window you should see a dividing line that cuts across the window, just above the merge pane.  In the example below, it's just above the text `Merged - Schiller's Glocke`.

[image: TortoiseMerge]

Position your cursor over the dividing bar and drag it up.  You should expose more merged lines at the expense of the diffs.

Comment: No dice. I've tried to pull that dividing bar up and nothing. That is why I posted the question. ;) I know it sounds like a connection error between the chair and the keyboard. But really it will not budge.

Comment: Are you actually in the 3 pane view (shown above) or the 2 pane view?  Sounds like maybe 2 pane view?

Comment: The bottom pane when in 2 pane view is the *line* diff bar which shows
the difference between a line in `Theirs` and a line in `Mine`. It can
only be exactly 2 lines high. If you are looking at long lines, use
Ctrl-wheel mouse to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 distint modes for the TortoiseMerge window.

a) When you right-click on a file thats in a commit and do a 'show changes' on it then you will get this wierd 3rd panel is fixed (and will only show 2 lines mode. You cannot resize it)

b) When you are doing a conflict/merge then is a lot larger and resizable (..which is the mode you are thinking of)